# JQuery ui datepicker for two dates

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to use datepicker for two date fields while keeping the same style that I created. The date must not be greater than the current date. Except that in my case when I choose a date in 2021 my condition doesn't work anymore and also the code repeats.

Is there a way to write something less repetitive?

```js
  // Generate a calendar to pick up a date
  // The chosen date can't be greater than today
  let datenow = new Date();
  let dd = String(datenow.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  let mm = String(datenow.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  let yyyy = datenow.getFullYear();
  datenow = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
  let twoDatepicker = $('[id="datepicker"]');
  $("#id_start_date").click(function () {
      $(twoDatepicker[0]).datepicker('update', new Date(datenow));
      $(twoDatepicker[0]).on('changeDate', function () {
          if ($(twoDatepicker[0]).datepicker('getFormattedDate') > datenow) {
              alert("You can't choose date greater than today");
              $(twoDatepicker[0]).datepicker('update', new Date(datenow));
          }
          else { $(twoDatepicker[0]).datepicker('getFormattedDate') }
      });
  }).on('change', function(){
      $('.datepicker').hide();
  });
  $("#id_end_date").click(function () {
      $(twoDatepicker[1]).datepicker('update', new Date(datenow));
      $(twoDatepicker[1]).on('changeDate', function () {
          if ($(twoDatepicker[1]).datepicker('getFormattedDate') > datenow) {
              alert("You can't choose date greater than today");
              $(twoDatepicker[1]).datepicker('update', new Date(datenow));
          }
          else { $(twoDatepicker[1]).datepicker('getFormattedDate') }
      });
  }).on('change', function(){
      $('.datepicker').hide();
  });
```

```css
/* Custom CSS datapicker */
/* hover previous and next month*/
#datepicker th.prev:hover{background:#F57C00}
#datepicker th.next:hover{background:#F57C00}
/* hover switch */
#datepicker th.datepicker-switch:hover{background:#F57C00}

/* DAY*/
/* hover on day */
#datepicker td.day:hover{background:#F57C00}
/* hover on active day */
#datepicker td.day:hover.active{background:#aa66cc}
/* active day */
#datepicker table tr td.active{background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#00838F,#00838F)}

/* MONTH */
/* hover month */
#datepicker span.month:hover{background:#F57C00}
#datepicker span.month.active{background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#00838F,#00838F)}
/* hover on active month */
#datepicker span.month.active:hover{background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#aa66cc,#aa66cc)}

/* YEAR */
/* hover year */
#datepicker span.year:hover{background:#F57C00}
#datepicker span.year.active{background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#00838F,#00838F)}
/* hover on active year */
#datepicker span.year.active:hover{background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#aa66cc,#aa66cc)}

/* DECADE */
/* hover decade */
#datepicker span.decade:hover{background:#F57C00}
#datepicker span.decade.active{background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#00838F,#00838F)}
/* hover on active year */
#datepicker span.decade.active:hover{background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#aa66cc,#aa66cc)}

/* CENTURY */
/* hover century */
#datepicker span.century:hover{background:#F57C00}
#datepicker span.century.active{background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#00838F,#00838F)}
/* hover on active century */
#datepicker span.century.active:hover{background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#aa66cc,#aa66cc)}

.datepicker-inline {
    background-color: var(--form-bg-color);
    border: 1px #f8f9fa solid;
}
.datepicker-days {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.datepicker-inline:hover {
    border: 1px #F57C00 solid;
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="td-margin-bottom-5" id="datepicker">
    <label for="id_start_date">Date greater than or equal to:</label>
    <input type="text" name="start_date" class="form-control form-form shadow-none td-margin-bottom-5 textarea_custom" name="start_date" placeholder="Search by date" id="id_start_date">
</div>
<div class="td-margin-bottom-5" id="datepicker">
    <label for="id_end_date">Date less than or equal to:</label>
    <input type="text" name="end_date" class="form-control form-form shadow-none td-margin-bottom-5 textarea_custom" name="end_date" placeholder="Search by date" id="id_end_date">
</div>
```

Comment: Don't think you're forced to use the native browser's `window.alert()` function. Create your own HTML element to show the message to the user.

Comment: @cheesyMan yes, which I intend to do later, but for now the `window.alert()` is just for testing purposes.

Comment: So, maybe I misunderstood your question :)

Comment: maybe you want to have a look at https://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/